# Adding binary numbers with a acumulator

Tags: c++, binary

I'm doing a code that takes a text that is converted to binary, the program need to add every number converted, what I'm doing is to create an acumulator to add all the numbers to a single one, there are 200 binary nombers, the program goes well until the 18 iteration

The libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 200
#include <bitset>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
```

This is the main:

```
int main()
{
    bitset<8>text[MAX];
    string myString = "2074656d7075732e20446f6e65632076697461652073617069656e207574206c696265726f2076656e656e617469732066617563696275732e204e756c6c616d207175697320616e74652e20457469616d2073697420616d6574206f7263692065676574";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i){
        text[i]=bitset<8>(myString.c_str()[i]);
    }
    int array[20];
    int i=0;
    long acumulator=0;
    bool f=0;


    for(int j=0;j<18;j++){
    if(f==0){
        string b = text[j].to_string();
        long bn1 = atoi(b.c_str());
        acumulator = add(bn1,0); 
        f=1;
    }else{
        string b = text[j].to_string();
        long bn1 = atoi(b.c_str());
        acumulator = add(bn1,acumulator); 
       }
    }
    cout<<acumulator;

    return 0;
 }
```

I convert the string into binary and save them into an array, then I call the "add" function, if its the first iteration, add the first number with a 0 and save the result in a var called "acumulator", then continue calling the function with the next number and the acumulator, all works till the 18 iteration, where start to adding weird numbers

The add function:

```
long add(long bn1,long bn2){
    int r=0, i=0;
    int sum[100];
    stringstream ss;
    while (bn1 != 0 || bn2 != 0) {
        sum[i++] = (int)((bn1 % 10 + bn2 % 10 + r) % 2);
        r = (int)((bn1 % 10 + bn2 % 10 + r) / 2);
        bn1 = bn1 / 10;
        bn2 = bn2 / 10;
    }
    if (r != 0){
        sum[i++] = r;
    }

    for (int j = i-1; j >=0; j--){
        ss << sum [j]; 
    }
    long result;
    ss >> result;

    return result;
 }
```

Here I do the binary add and the result is transformed into a long, and return it to use it into the next iteration

And don't know why stop working in the 18 iteration, any idea of what is happening?

Comment: When you used the debugger to debug your application, what did you observe?

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat the tag information in your post title. The tagging system works extremely well here and doesn't need any help.